# Affordable CLI enabled devices?

Tags: cli, packet-tracer

Im new to networking and i've been fiddling with Cisco's Packet Tracer for students

Every device has a CLI you can access via console cable or other means to configure your network

Now to my dismay I've browsed through available routers and switches to discover only high end expensive devices offer these fine grained configuration facilities

Question: Is there just no way to put this knowleadge to use with a lower budget? If so, I can't seem identify CLI enabled devices on the price ranges I can afford

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unfortunately, product and/or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic here. Have you checked EBay? There are also rack rentals, through which you can get access to advanced networking equipment.

Comment: Really? That again? Is it safe to assume I can't excercise networking in real life without either being a millionaire or a big company's employee working with its networks then? (BTW I did search EBay as suggested in the question)

Comment: You did search ebay and found nothing in your budget? Seems you budget is quite low, there's ton of routers below 100$/€. You should search for open source network projects, there's many available at no cost. My company use some of them in production networks.

Comment: Didn't find any with a console port though. Also, thanks for mentioning those open source network projects, a few links would have been nicer though

Comment: As frustrating it can be, as said by Ron, product recommendation is off-topic here, but there's  [Stack Exchange Hardware Recommendation](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com) and the [software](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) one.  But here is a [link](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_sacat=0&_nkw=cisco%20router&_udhi=45&_trksid=p2045573.m1684.l5985). Except for linksys and small business stuff, all those devices have console port.

Comment: Unfortunately, it usually costs money for an education beyond the public school system. If medical schools were plentiful and cheap, we would have a lot more doctors. The reason that there are so many inexpensive devices and labs on EBay is that people like you buy them, learn with them, then resell them on EBay. Many practicing network engineers have used this model for years. The rack rentals are also relatively inexpensive, often include lab exercises you can use, and you can buy just what you need.

Comment: Affordable, with CLI and quite good, only one brand come to my mind. Mikrotik, check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of systems on the market that have a CLI. Some are even very close to the Cisco IOS CLI you've been learning. However, at the end of the day, ever vendor will have their own flavor of CLI. Yes, many dirt-cheap, "web-managed" products will be lacking a physical console. (a console is, after all, extra hardware that adds to the material and production costs.)

If you want to work with Cisco gear, then do so. It doesn't take "millions" to get a decent collection of routers and switches. No, you will not find current generation kit on ebay (or anywhere else) for pennies. But older, end-of-life gear can be found for sub-100$ -- *we* know it's possible because *we've all* bought the things.